# Connect by and level - hour interval

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following data:

```
ID  SESSION START_DATE          END_DATE
1   A       01/01/2016 22:35    02/01/2016 02:35
1   B       02/01/2016 02:35    02/01/2016 04:45
2   A       01/01/2016 00:00    01/01/2016 02:00
2   B       01/01/2016 02:00    01/01/2016 03:30
```

And I need to return like this:

```
ID  SESSION START_DATE          END_DATE
1   A       01/01/2016 22:35    01/01/2016 22:59
1   A       01/01/2016 23:00    01/01/2016 23:59
1   A       02/01/2016 00:00    02/01/2016 00:59
1   A       02/01/2016 01:00    02/01/2016 01:59
1   A       02/01/2016 02:00    02/01/2016 02:35
1   B       02/01/2016 02:35    02/01/2016 02:59
1   B       02/01/2016 03:00    02/01/2016 03:59
1   B       02/01/2016 04:00    02/01/2016 04:45
2   A       01/01/2016 00:00    01/01/2016 00:59
2   A   ...
```

any help?

Comment: What you have tried ??

Comment: SELECT ID,SESSION,STAR_DATE,END_DATE
FROM
(SELECT 
SESSION, 
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(GREATEST(STAR_DATE,TRUNC(STAR_DATE)+LEVEL-1),'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') STAR_DATE,
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(LEAST(END_DATE,TRUNC(END_DATE)+LEVEL-1/(24*60*60)),'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') END_DATE,
ID                               
FROM 
(
SELECT
ID,    
SESSION,
STAR_DATE,
nvl(END_DATE,sysdate) END_DATE
FROM TBL
ORDER BY
SESSION,
STAR_DATE  DESC
)
WHERE LEVEL<=(TRUNC(END_DATE)-TRUNC(STAR_DATE))+1 
CONNECT BY ROWID=PRIOR ROWID
AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL
)

Comment: add this to your question .

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, you just have to play a little with hour extractions:

```
create table connect_by_hour_test(id number, sess varchar2(1), start_date date, end_date date);

insert into connect_by_hour_test (id, sess, start_date, end_date) values (1, 'A', to_date('01/01/2016 22:30', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'), to_date('02/01/2016 02:35', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'));
insert into connect_by_hour_test (id, sess, start_date, end_date) values (1, 'B', to_date('02/01/2016 02:35', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'), to_date('02/01/2016 04:45', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'));
insert into connect_by_hour_test (id, sess, start_date, end_date) values (2, 'A', to_date('01/01/2016 00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'), to_date('01/01/2016 02:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'));
insert into connect_by_hour_test (id, sess, start_date, end_date) values (2, 'B', to_date('01/01/2016 02:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'), to_date('01/01/2016 03:30', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'));

commit;

with max_level as (
select id, sess, ceil((end_date - start_date) / (1/24)) as val from connect_by_hour_test ) -- get the max number of iterations for each (id, sess) pair
select distinct 
    id, 
    sess,
    decode(level, 1, to_char(start_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'), to_char(trunc(start_date, 'hh24') + 1/24 * level - 1/24, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi')) start_date, -- if first iteration in pair show the start_date, otherwise show the start date, plus the number of hours for the current iteration(first iteration - 1 hour, 2nd iteration - two hours, etc) minus one minute
    decode(level, (select val from max_level ml where ml.id = src.id and ml.sess = src.sess), to_char(end_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'), to_char(trunc(start_date, 'hh24') + 1/24 * level - 1/24/60, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi')) end_date -- if last iteration show end_date, otherwise show value from previous iteration plus one minute
  from 
    connect_by_hour_test src
  connect by 
    trunc(start_date, 'hh24') + 1/24 * (level - 1) <= end_date order by 1,2;
```

Edit: Corrections made after feedback, added step to be level - 1 and max_level calculated as ceil, instead of trunc, of end_date - start_date

Comment: ID SESS START_DATE END_DATE
1 A 01/01/2016 22:30 01/01/2016 22:59
1 A 01/01/2016 23:00 01/01/2016 23:59
1 A 02/01/2016 00:00 02/01/2016 00:59
1 A 02/01/2016 01:00 02/01/2016 02:35
1 B 02/01/2016 02:35 02/01/2016 02:59
1 B 02/01/2016 03:00 02/01/2016 04:45
2 A 01/01/2016 00:00 01/01/2016 00:59
2 A 01/01/2016 01:00 01/01/2016 02:00
2 B 01/01/2016 02:00 01/01/2016 03:30
***some rows are not in 1 hour interval

Comment: The step was not correctly calculated, now the the 1 hour interval is respected.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT session,
              id,
              st,
              end
FROM (    SELECT DECODE(LEVEL, 1, start_date, TRUNC(start_date, 'HH') + (LEVEL - 1) / 24) st,
                 PRIOR id p_id,
                 id,
                 PRIOR session p_session,
                 session,
                 LEAST(end_date, TRUNC(start_date, 'HH') + (LEVEL) / 24 - 1 / 24 / 60) end
            FROM tab
      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= EXTRACT(HOUR FROM end_date - start_date) + 1)
WHERE    (    p_id = id
          AND p_session = session)
      OR (p_id IS NULL)
```

I would like to avoid the usage of DISTINCT, but could not find a way, hope  someone else could give a better solution

Comment: I had the same issue with DISTINCT in my solution, couldn't figure rows are multiplied with level value.

Answer (score 0):

select level,
NR_ATENDIMENTO,
CD_SETOR_ATENDIMENTO,
greatest(DT_ENTRADA_UNIDADE, trunc(DT_ENTRADA_UNIDADE+(level-1)/24, 'hh24')) DT_ENTRADA_UNIDADE,
to_char(trunc(DT_ENTRADA_UNIDADE, 'hh24') + 1/24 * level - 1/24/60, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') DT_SAIDA_UNIDADE
from 
(
SELECT
        CD_SETOR_ATENDIMENTO,
        NR_SEQ_INTERNO,
        DT_ENTRADA_UNIDADE,
        nvl(DT_SAIDA_UNIDADE,sysdate) DT_SAIDA_UNIDADE,
        NR_ATENDIMENTO
FROM      ATEND_PACIENTE_UNIDADE 
WHERE OBTER_TIPO_UNIDADE_ATEND(NR_ATENDIMENTO, NR_SEQ_INTERNO, IE_PASSAGEM_SETOR) NOT IN ('S')
AND nr_atendimento = 831838 
ORDER BY  NR_ATENDIMENTO,
CD_SETOR_ATENDIMENTO,
DT_ENTRADA_UNIDADE  DESC
)
WHERE 1=1 
CONNECT BY ROWID=PRIOR ROWID
and trunc(DT_ENTRADA_UNIDADE, 'hh24') + 1/24 * (level - 1) <= nvl(DT_SAIDA_UNIDADE,sysdate)
AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL
order by 2,3,4;